# find income tax based on annual income and marital status - java program

Tags: java

I'm not sure what the issue is. The top of the console says  after the user inputs annual income. There are no errors shown in the console itself.

The program is to find income tax based on annual income and marital status.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class taxpayers {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String maritalStatus;
        System.out.println("What is your marital status? Type 'M' for married and 'S' for single.");

        maritalStatus = sc.next(); //reads next input as marital status

        System.out.println("What is your annual income?");
        double income;
        income = sc.nextDouble();

        double marriedTax; //declare these doubles before beginning the if/then statements
        double singleTax; 

        if (maritalStatus.equals("M")) {
```

Comment: Hi Kenwoodjen, when asking a question it pays to to state what the program is doing and what it should be doing, rather than just say here's my code(please read my mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just small syntax error

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String maritalStatus;
    System.out.println("What is your marital status? Type 'M' for married and 'S' for single.");

    maritalStatus = sc.next(); //reads next input as marital status

    System.out.println("What is your annual income?");
    double income;
    income = sc.nextDouble();

    double marriedTax = 0; //declare these doubles before beginning the if/then statements
    double singleTax; 

    if (maritalStatus.equals("M")) {

        if (income > 0 && income <= 39000) {
            marriedTax = income * .15;
        }

        else if (income > 39000 && income <= 94250) {
            marriedTax = (income - 39000) * .28 + 5850;
        }

        else if (income > 94250 && income <= 143600) {
            marriedTax = (income - 94250) * .31 + 21320;
        }

        else if (income > 143600 && income <= 256500) {
            marriedTax = (income - 143600) * .36 + 36618.5;
        }

        else if (income > 256500) {

            marriedTax = (income - 256500) * 39.6 + 77262.5;
        }

        System.out.printf("Your income taxes are $%.2f.", marriedTax );
    };


    if (maritalStatus.equals("S")) {

        if (income > 0 && income <= 23350) {
            singleTax = income * .15;
        }

        else if (income > 23350 && income <= 56550) {
            singleTax = (income - 23350) * .28 + 3502.5;
        }

        else if (income > 56550 && income <= 117950) {
            singleTax = (income - 56550) * .31 + 12798.5;
        }

        else if (income > 117950 && income <= 256500) {
            singleTax = (income - 117950) * .36 + 31832.5;
        }

        else if (income > 256500); {
            singleTax = (income - 256500) * 39.6 + 81710.5;
        }

        System.out.printf("Your income taxes are $%.2f.", singleTax);
    };

    sc.close();

}
```

Comment: Can you please describe for us what the small syntax error was?

Answer (score 1):

Your last else if conditions are incorrect

```
else if (income > 256500); <-- this end the condition

else if (income > 256500); <-- this end the condition
```

Remove semicolns at the end and use {

try like this

```
public class taxpayers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String maritalStatus;
        System.out.println("What is your marital status? Type 'M' for married and 'S' for single.");

        maritalStatus = sc.next(); //reads next input as marital status

        System.out.println("What is your annual income?");
        double income;
        income = sc.nextDouble();

        double marriedTax; //declare these doubles before beginning the if/then statements
        double singleTax;

        if (maritalStatus.equals("M")) {

            if (income > 0 && income <= 39000) {
                marriedTax = income * .15;
            } else if (income > 39000 && income <= 94250) {
                marriedTax = (income - 39000) * .28 + 5850;
            } else if (income > 94250 && income <= 143600) {
                marriedTax = (income - 94250) * .31 + 21320;
            } else if (income > 143600 && income <= 256500) {
                marriedTax = (income - 143600) * .36 + 36618.5;
            } else if (income > 256500){
                marriedTax = (income - 256500) * 39.6 + 77262.5;
            }
            System.out.printf("Your income taxes are $%.2f.", marriedTax);
        };

        if (maritalStatus.equals("S")) {
            if (income > 0 && income <= 23350) {
                singleTax = income * .15;
            } else if (income > 23350 && income <= 56550) {
                singleTax = (income - 23350) * .28 + 3502.5;
            } else if (income > 56550 && income <= 117950) {
                singleTax = (income - 56550) * .31 + 12798.5;
            } else if (income > 117950 && income <= 256500) {
                singleTax = (income - 117950) * .36 + 31832.5;
            } else if (income > 256500){
                singleTax = (income - 256500) * 39.6 + 81710.5;
            }
            System.out.printf("Your income taxes are $%.2f.", singleTax);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```